# How to Properly Limit Google Provider Domain in Next Auth

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I understand how to restrict the google email provider that can log into my web. for example, the domain that I allow is an email like this jhon@students.stanford.ac.uk. the problem arises when I try to log in with the email alex@gmail.com.

it is true that alex@gmail.com cannot be logged into my web. but when I log in with alex@gmail.com next auth redirects alex to the http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=AccessDenied page.

this is the callback code that I use to restrict the domains that can log in to my web

```
callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user }) {
      try {
        // user login with gmail
        if (user.email && user.email.endsWith('students.stanford.ac.uk')) {
          return true
        }

        return false
      } catch (error) {
        return false
      }
    },
```

what I expect is when logging in with alex@gmail.com instead of redirecting the alex to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=AccessDenied I want to display a pop up message to alex that he must log in using email alex@students.stanford.ac.uk

can we achieve this

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches to restricting access to your website to users from a specific domain.

In this example, I am using the `GoogleProvider` and specifying the authorization parameter with the Google OAuth 2.0 authorization URL. The `hd` parameter in the authorization URL is set to `domain.com`, indicating that only users with email addresses from the specified domain will be allowed to authenticate.

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? '',
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? '',
      authorization:
        'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&hd=domain.com'
    })
  ]
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Alternatively, here I am using the callbacks property to define a `signIn` callback. Inside the callback function, you check if the user's email ends with `@domain.com`. If it does, the user is allowed to sign in; otherwise, they are denied access.

```
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? '',
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? ''
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user }) {
      if (user.email && user.email.endsWith('@domain.com')) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading the documentation it turns out that this can be realized by creating a callback like this. By returning the URL that will be the notification page related to logging in with an unauthorized email.. Hope this help

```
callbacks: {
    async signIn({ account, user }) {
      // user login with gmail
      if (user.email && user.email.endsWith('students.stanford.ac.uk')) {
        return true
      }

      // user login with sso
      if (account?.provider === 'credentials') {
        return true
      }

      return '/auth/signin?errorCode=403'
    },
  },
```